# Angular ng-grid in a nested tab

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an app based on [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUbCR8?p=preview).

My app has grown & it probably too large & complex to post here, so let's just continue to discuss the Plunk on which it is based.

Basically, I just want to use an ng-grid, which I will populate with JSON data received from a server, on one of the nested tabs.

That wasn't working, so I tried to simplify the problem by using the exact code of the ng-grid example (see http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/).

That still wasn't working, so I tried to simplify the problem by adding the ng-grid demo to the Plunk on which my code is based.

That still isn't working, as shown by [this forked Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qbSBsT?p=preview). If you look at it, you can search for `@@@@ begin @@@@` and `@@@@ end @@@@` to see what I added to each of the three files.

Note: In my app, I can see the table contents, but left aligned & overwriting each other, as if there was a maximum width or other CSS attribute involved. In my forked plunk, the grid appears to be empty.

Comment: what data does batarang show for your scope?

Comment: Sorry, I am new & still struggling to get it to work :-(

Comment: no shame in that, I dropped the batarang keyword as a hint, figuring you didn't know about it and how critical it can be to solving these probs in angular.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forked plunk did not include the `ngGrid` scripts or jQuery, which it [depends on](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/).

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="ng-grid@*" data-semver="2.0.7" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.7/ng-grid.js"></script>
<script data-require="ng-grid@*" data-semver="2.0.7" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.7/ng-grid-flexible-height.min.js"></script>
```

You also need to inject `ngGrid` into your app:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'ui.router', 'ngGrid'])
```

Here is an update to your plunk, with these changes included: http://plnkr.co/edit/V0itOu?p=preview

Comment: Thank you ever so much!! I wonder why I have layout problems. Probably CSS, I would guess. Look out for a follow up question ;-)