# AngulrJS ng-grid layout is wrong; looks to me like a CSS thing

Tags: css

It is *possible* that this is an AngularJS problem, but since it affects only appearance, I suspect CSS.

I am trying to use [an ng-Grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) but the appearance is wrong.

At first I thought it was an Angular thing, as I wanted the grid to appear on a nested tab. However, [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177490/angular-ng-grid-in-a-nested-tab) elicited [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/V0itOu?p=preview) where the grid displays correctly using nested tabs.

It displays wrongly in my app, so I have ripped as much as I can out of the app, leaving [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qdRITZoTIgWBk055B1EF?p=preview) which shows how it displays wrongly.

Can anyone explain what I am dong wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just missing the `ngGrid` stylesheet:

```
<link data-require="ng-grid@*" data-semver="2.0.7" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.7/ng-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Also, I included `style.css` which contains the basic styles from the `ngGrid` [samples](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/).  Without this, the grid will be very short:

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px
}
```

Here is an update to your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/f512dmY617NeOC0aQybi?p=preview

Comment: @Jwittwer +1 & the answer, thank you very, very much. One further question. I want to populate the grid with JSON data received from a server. How do I make the height "as high as it needs to be to show all data without  a scrollbar?

Comment: have you tried this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275857/turnoff-scrolling-within-angular-ui-ng-grid